# GACK - Error ID: 2052121255-69552 (1912390556)

Tags: gack, remedyforce

I'm trying to get access to an Incident in my remedyforce console and when I access to every one of them I got with this error.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Can you elaborate a bit on what you're doing to get this error?

Generally speaking, GACKs are internal Salesforce errors, and you can read up more about them here: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2015/02/gack.html. If you got this GACK via the remedyforce managed package,  even if you were able to determine the cause, I don't think you can do much about it. I'd start a case with SF, and give RemedyForce access to your system so they can get more details.